# Getting error: undefined method `greater_than_or_equal_to' for Shoulda::Matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec2, shoulda

Here is the spec I am trying to get to pass:

```
context "when validating format of attributes" do
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:price).greater_than_or_equal_to(0.01) }
end
```

I have `rspec` and `shoulda-matchers` installed. But I am getting `undefined method`greater_than_or_equal_to'`

Now that method isn't in the documentation but it does exist here:

https://github.com/moffff/shoulda-matchers/commit/7da06487d25c27d59d11fb7f2962e7ff345e45c4

So why is this not working? What should I do to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method does not exists in original `thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers` that is in you app. The version you're referring is a fork of original gem.

You can use this gem instead of original one, just set it source in Gemfile

```
gem 'shoulda-matchers', :git => 'https://github.com/moffff/shoulda-matchers.git'
```

But you should understand that forked and modified version can work unstable, does not include latest updates and fixes, and so on.

Comment: so that's how you use a forked gem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It must be `is_greater_than_or_equal_to` (with a `is_` prefix), not `greater_than_or_equal_to`.

See the docs: https://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v4.1.2/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel.html#validate_numericality_of-instance_method